# What is the objective function that Latent Dirichlet Allocation (LDA) minimizes?

Tags: lda

Latent Dirichlet Allocation (LDA) is a generative model which produces a list of topics. Each topic is represented by a distribution over words.

Questions:

- What is the objective function that it tries to minimize? Can someone
  explain it in simpler way? The mathematical formula and the intuition
  behind it?
- Secondly, After building the LDA model how we validate the model? I
  have heard perplexity as one metric, but what is perplexity about?
- Does bias, Variance problem also exists in LDA? If yes, when it can
  occur?